# Try to post JSON.stringify object to aspnet mvc controller - bad request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, bad-request, iis-8

I'm trying to post a JS Object stored in a hidden field:

```
$("#hdnArr").val(JSON.stringify(arr));

<pre>

    $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                   //
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {
                   //
                }
            });

</pre>
```

Locally it is working fine, but in a production server (windows 2012 server with IIS 8), it is returng a Bad Request Error. With Firebug I checked that my hidden value is like this:

```
hdnArr=%5B%7B%22Type%22%3A%22%22%2C%22TypeB%22%3A%22%22%2C%22TypeC%22%3A%22%22%2C%22TypeD%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D
```

This problem is basically the `%` character. How can I enable my server to accept this char?

Comment: Did you try fixing the content-type ? example : contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could solve this problem just switching the Managed Pipeline from App Pool to Classic Mode.